# Web flow in Grails - confused

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I have nothing but pain every time I touch web flow, I thought things might be more simple and understandable in the world of grails as apposed to Spring MVC but it seems not.

I have a simple situation where I want to start off a web flow with a prepopulated command object already in the flow scope when the first page of the web flow displays. The command object is basically going to hold copies of values form a domain object

here's my command object:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable(nullable=false)
class PatientEditFlowCommand implements Serializable{

StepOneCommand stepOneCommand

PatientEditFlowCommand(Patient patient){

    stepOneCommand = new StepOneCommand(
            patientName : "${patient.appUser?.firstName} ${patient.appUser?.lastName}",
            patientDoctorId : patient.doctor?.id,
            patientNurseId : patient.nurse?.id,
            patientStartDate : patient.startDate,
            patientEndDate : patient.endDate,
            patientDrugRegimeId: patient.regime?.id
    )

}

static constraints = {


}
}


@grails.validation.Validateable(nullable=false)
class StepOneCommand implements Serializable{

String patientName //wont be editable

Long patientDoctorId  //user id of assigned doctor
Long patientNurseId   //user id of assigned doctor

Date patientStartDate
Date patientEndDate

Long patientDrugRegimeId

static constraints = {
    patientDoctorId(nullable: false)
    patientNurseId(nullable: false)
    patientStartDate(nullable: false)
    patientEndDate(nullable: false)
    patientDrugRegimeId(nullable: false)
}
}


@grails.validation.Validateable(nullable=false)
class StepTwoCommand implements Serializable{

static constraints = {

}
}
```

Heres my flow inside my controller:

```
    def newEditFlow = {

    init {
        //start the flow by transferring domain obj into a command object
        action {
            Patient patient = Patient.get(params.id)
            [patientEditFlowCommand:new PatientEditFlowCommand(patient)]
            success()
        }
        on ("success"){

        }.to "stepOne"

    }

    stepOne{

        on("next") {

        }.to("stepTwo")

        on("cancel").to("finish")

    }

    stepTwo{

        on("next") {

        }.to("stepThree")

        on("previous").to("stepOne")
    }

    stepThree{

        on("next") {

        }.to("stepFour")

        on("previous").to("stepTwo")
    }

    stepFour{

        on("next") {

        }.to("finish")

        on("previous").to("stepThree")
    }

    finish{
        redirect(controller:'patient',action: "list")
    }
}
```

but when i navigate to the first transtion I get this

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
/ivfportal/patient/newEdit/3
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
null
Around line 74 of GrailsFlowExecutorImpl.java

71:        }72:73:        try {74:            return super.resumeExecution(flowExecutionKey, context);75:        }76:        catch (FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException e) {77:            if (e.getCause() instanceof SnapshotUnmarshalException) {
Around line 53 of GrailsFlowHandlerAdapter.java

50:            request.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.CONTROLLER, controllerInstance);51:        }52:53:        return super.handle(request, response, handler);54:    }55:56:    public void setGrailsApplication(GrailsApplication grailsApplication) {
Around line 189 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java

186:            if (method == null) {187:               log.debug("No cacheable method found for {}:{} {}",188:                     new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });189:               chain.doFilter(request, response);190:              return;191:         }192:           Collection<CacheOperation> cacheOperations = cacheOperationSource.getCacheOperations(
Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java

60:     try {61:            // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping62:         if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {63:                doFilter(request, response, chain);64:          }65:            else {66:               chain.doFilter(req, res);
Around line 45 of DevModeSanityFilter.groovy

42:            response.contentType = "text/html"43:            response.writer << RELOADING_DOC44:        } else {45:            chain.doFilter(request, response)46:47:            if (request.getAttribute('resources.need.layout')) {48:                def dispositionsLeftOver = DispositionsUtils.getRequestDispositionsRemaining(request)
Around line 53 of GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java

50:51:      applyAnonymousForThisRequest((HttpServletRequest)req);52:53:        chain.doFilter(req, res);54:    }55:56: protected void applyAnonymousForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
Around line 139 of RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy
```

anyone see where I'm going wrong ? Is there a simpler but still tidy way of collecting data over a multi page flow in Grails ?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass params over the flow via the conversation.
conversation.patient = Patient.get(params.id)
also every class you use in web flow must be serializable